# Handle form-data using Azure APIM policy

Tags: azure-api-management

**Disclaimer : I am very new to Azure API Management**

Hi Friends,

I have the following requirement to be accomplished -

1. The user will upload an image from a mobile app as "form-data".
2. An API will be called through Azure APIM and the image will be stored in Blob.
3. The call should also invoke a backend API at the same time along with the image which does processing and gives the result back.

Could you please suggest how should I proceed on writing the APIM policy for this. I am aware of handling the image at the API side if it comes as part of JSON data. I am just looking for suggestions on the APIM part or more precisely about how to write the policy if the image is part of form-data.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks and  Regards,
Amit Anand

Answer (score 0):

> I am just looking for suggestions on the APIM part or more precisely about how to write the policy if the image is part of form-data.

I have reached out to the APIM team for this scenario and they've confirmed **this isn't supported at this time**. The recommendation is to use JSON payload and, parse & consume accordingly.

If you feel strongly about this, please consider submitting a feature request on Azure [UserVoice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/248703-api-management) for the APIM team to review for the product roadmap.

Refer to this [issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/52376).